# Junit automation test in sequential order

Tags: java, selenium, junit

I created Junit test in one class in Java. Basically one class with multiple test test cases within that class and when the test runs the chrome page comes up with a blank page. It runs out of order and its like for each @test senario it resets bringing up another chrome page **instead of executing each test within the same page** and going to the next test so on. When I run this all in **( one @test case ) it works fine.**

I use protractor and program the same way with **describes** and **its** and have no problem. I am trying to do the same in Java with Junit so if a test case fails I can go to that one Test case quickly. I have a @Before and @Test and @after annotations

Please help I am not as experienced with Java.My code is below.

```
 public class BankrateAlt {
  private WebDriver driver;
  private String baseUrl;
  private boolean acceptNextAlert = true;
  private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();

  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\eclipse\\Java\\chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe");  
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\eclipse\\Java\\geckodriver\\geckodriver.exe");  
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    baseUrl = "http://www.bankrate.com/";
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }

  @Test 
  public void moveToElementMortgages() throws InterruptedException{
      Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
      WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.linkText("MORTGAGES"));
      builder.moveToElement(element).perform();
      Thread.sleep(2000);
  }

  @Test 
  public void clickOnCalculators() throws InterruptedException{
      Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
      WebElement calculator = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[href*='mortgage-calculators']"));
      builder.moveToElement(calculator).perform();
      calculator.click();
      Thread.sleep(2000);
  }

  @Test 
  public void nextPageScrollDown() throws InterruptedException{ 
      ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("scroll(0, 400)");
      Thread.sleep(2000);
  }

  @Test 
  public void clickMorgageLoanPaymentCalc() throws InterruptedException{  

      WebElement MorgageCalc = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Mortgage loan payment calculator"));  
      MorgageCalc.click();
      Thread.sleep(2000);
  }

  @Test 
  public void scrollDownCalcPage() throws InterruptedException{  

      ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("scroll(0, 400)");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
  }

  @Test 
  public void clearMortgageSendKeys() throws InterruptedException{  

      WebElement MortgageField = driver.findElement(By.id("KJE-LOAN_AMOUNT"));
      MortgageField.clear();
      Thread.sleep(1000);

      WebElement LoanAmount = driver.findElement(By.name("LOAN_AMOUNT"));
      LoanAmount.sendKeys("$240,000");
      Thread.sleep(3000);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a unit test that should never be required but you have an integration test workflow where this is somehow useful to get more details failures.

You can use the `FixMethodOrder` annotation on the test class but you would need to name your methods in a proper way. I would suggest a prefix to your current names like `step1_`, `step2_` etc.

```
@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
public class BankrateAlt {
  @Test 
  public void step1_moveToElementMortgages() {…}
  @Test
  public void step2_clickOnCalculators() {…}
  …
}
```

As the setup is done per method you have to switch to the one per class behaviour of `@BeforeClass` (has to be static).

Comment: In eclipse when I use @FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING) I get "method sorts cant be defined to a variable"

Comment: Problem I have now is that it the page come up but does not go to the url automatically will i have to input that on the 1st step?

Comment: I fixed this by adding another @test annotation before step1 by directing webdriver to go to url first... thanks for all your help guys :) .

Comment: hmm, are you sure you didn't drop anything during former changes? The baseUrl is used nowhere...

Comment: hey I added 5 more @test annotations and they are no longer in order how can I fix?

Comment: Check the method names, they are ordered by ascii, not numeric

Comment: I know it has been a while however everytime i run this code methods are shuffled around why is that?

Answer (score 3):

JUnit doesn't run tests in order, as unit tests should be able to run in isolation (and as a consequence in any order).

This is a trivial fix, but something you can do is remove all the `@Test` annotations from all methods and add the following test:

```
@Test 
public void fullTest() {
  moveToElementMortgages();
  clickOnCalculators();
  nextPageScrollDown(); 
  clickMorgageLoanPaymentCalc();
  scrollDownCalcPage();
  clearMortgageSendKeys();
}
```

If you want to do this in a more refined way, do read about `Page Object pattern`. Or the more recent `Screenplay pattern`.

Comment: Problem I have now is that it the page come up but does not go to the url automatically will i have to input that on the 1st step?

Comment: I fixed this by adding another @test annotation before step1 by directing webdriver to go to url first... thanks for all your help guys :) .

Answer (score 0):

@Before ist executed before each @Test method
@BeforeClass is what you want.

```
@BeforeClass
public static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception { 

}
```

To run the tests ordered you can use the @FixMethodOrder annotation.

Comment: Problem I have now is that it the page comes up but does not go to the url automatically will i have to input that on the 1st step?

Comment: I fixed this by adding another @test annotation before step1 by directing webdriver to go to url first... thanks for all your help guys :) .